# Glide use default image when onLoadFailed()

Tags: android, android-glide

I use glide version 4.7.1
I wanna use default image when onLoadFailed.

this is my code

```
Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
        // fail
        // How can i use default image in imgvAssetPicture?
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
        // success
        imgvLoadingProgressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imgvAssetPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return false;
    }
}).into(imgvAssetPicture);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 Glide.with(passContext)
.applyDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions()
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user_default)
.error(R.drawable.ic_user_default))
.load(url)
.into(image);
```

With version 4.7.1 (you are using), you can easily set these options.

- `placeHolder` which shows when there is not image.
- `error` when some URL fails to load.

**Bonus**

Are you using some `ProgressBar` with setting visibility, that's very old way to do.

See  [CircularProgressDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CircularProgressDrawable), which is very easy to use. Just pass this `CircularProgressDrawable` in your `placeHolder`.

Comment: How come I can't find symbol CircularProgressDrawable?

Answer (score 0):

Just Copy and Past these line of code wherever you want to use

Easy and simple

```
val circularProgressDrawable = CircularProgressDrawable(mContext)
circularProgressDrawable.strokeWidth = 5f
circularProgressDrawable.centerRadius = 30f
circularProgressDrawable.start()

        Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(specificCategoryObject.imgUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.circularProgressDrawable)
            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
            .error(R.drawable.img_place_holder)
            .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {

                override fun onLoadFailed(
                    e: GlideException?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Drawable>?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                circularProgressDrawable.alpha = 0
                    return false
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: Drawable?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Drawable>?,
                    dataSource: DataSource?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean,
                ): Boolean {
                circularProgressDrawable.alpha = 0    
                    return false
                }
            })
            .into(holder.ivProductImage)
```